# SQL Server : number of pages bigger than it should be

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I have a database in SQL Server 2012 Express and there is one particular table which I am struggling to understand.

Said table is has a CI and the following properties:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Hourly_Flows]
(
    [S_ID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [FromID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ToID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Hour8760] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [FromTo] [smallint] NULL,
    [ToFrom] [smallint] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK__oHF_Hour__60BEC9D565570293] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([S_ID] ASC, [FromID] ASC, [ToID] ASC, [Hour8760] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
             ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I created a new empty DB, with the exact same table and inserted all the records into it, the size of the new and old table is below:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    Table     |     Old      |     New      |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| RowCounts    | 109,911,720  | 109,911,720  |
| TotalPages   | 436,323      | 259,137      |
| UsedPages    | 436,270      | 259,098      |
| DataPages    | 434,434      | 258,009      |
| TotalSpaceMB | 3,408        | 2,024        |
| UsedSpaceMB  | 3,408        | 2,024        |
| DataSpaceMB  | 3,394        | 2,015        |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

As you can see the amount of pages and size is much smaller in the new table. Before inserting the data in the original table I tried truncated the table, dropped and recreated, cleantable and always get the same results.

Not sure what I am missing here, I have the same results if I re-insert the data into the original table. The only other issue could be that the DB is growing over the 10GB size limit of SQL Server Express databases, but not sure why this could make a difference.

The table used to have more columns which were deleted (hence we truncated it), we do this often but this is the first time it does not reduce its size.

Comment: dbs naturally build "cruft" inside, and when you dump and import into a new one, you get a nice clean "new" structure without that cruft and wasted space.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of pages and data depend on many variables :

1- count of insert , update and delete : cause in some pages become empty locations .

2- own Database fill factor : this parameter indicate how much a page could fill . (for reserve location in page for future use )

3- collation of database : In some collations , same data use more or less amount of space .

at end Marc is correct , new database means a clean surface to write data in clean way .

Comment: Thanks Amir, I spotted that the log file suddenly went up to over 20GB, I shrank it (I know the implications of this) and did a drop and recreated of the table and re-inserted the data. This time the size of the table is as expected. Any idea if the size of the log in a SQL Express 2012 database can have implications?

Comment: If the log is not matter for you , you can set recovery model of your db to simple . Then there is no logging in log files .